# Can a Magic User cast 'Illusion Disguise' on someone even though they don't agree with it

Tags: magic, gurps, gurps-4e

I am currently reading 'Gurps 4th Magic' and the spell 'Illusion Disguise' just says that you have to create a basic illusion and then use 'Illusion Disguise' to superimpose it.

However it never talks about the wearer. Could he just resist it? I can imagine a few situations where it is useful to put an illusion on someone. For example to discredit them in front of a crowd etc.

So, is there a rule that stops them from just putting it on anyone they want or would that fall into houserules?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like no, an unwilling subject can't resist an Illusion Disguise spell. Pages 13–14 describe *Resisted Spells*, but unlike some spells that have a target (e.g., mind control spells), Illusion Disguise does not have a Resistance note.

That said, if you're the GM and your world's magic works in such a way that you think the target *should* be able to resist, it's as easy as saying so. The rules on pages 13–14 describe how to handle it, and you only need to decide which of HT or Will should be use to resist with (Will seems like the sensible choice here).

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Would the target necessarily be aware of the spell cast in your world? That would be an important data point as to whether the target 'should' be able to resist.

Comment: @EFH Not in GURPS (barring the usual GM powers to change that, of course). Same page cited above: even unconscious subjects can resist a Resisted spell.